# Why Spring does not allow exclusive lock on read operation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Does anyone know why Spring does not allow to put @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) on read operations?

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Human findByNameAndStreet(String name, String street);
```

And also why EntityManager itself allows you to put exclusive lock on read operation?

```
entityManager.createQuery("select o from Human o where o.name= :name and o.street= :street", Human.class)
            .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).setParameter("name", name).setParameter("street", street).getSingleResult();
```

Bottom line, on same select query in Spring I can't put WRITE lock, and with EntityManager I'm able. I don't really know why Spring does not let you do same thing.

Comment: What effect do you expect from the pessimistic write lock?

Comment: To make exclusive lock on reading row. Code flow is specific, so first read transaction should lock that row, and next ones should wait until first one is finished. I was able to implement that with EntityManager, but I would like to know why Spring does not let you put exclusive lock on select query.

Comment: I guess because your transactional boundaries are wrongly (or not) defined.

Comment: @alxbxbx I think you are misusing database locks as a way to synchronize and coordinate application flow.

Comment: @M. Denium you are right. Can you please make comment, so I can mark it as the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use locking you have to have proper transactional boundaries. If you don't have them the only call the lock will work for is the `findByNameAndStreet`.

However if you would call this method from a service method that itself is transactional the lock would span the whole transactional service method.

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed. Thanks a lot!